# Mysqli loop, returns only one

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I'm trying to create multiple dropdowns, but only the last item in the array is used.

```
$arr = explode("\n", $ingredients);
foreach($arr as $value){

print '<select size="1" name="a[]"><option>'.$value.'</option>';

$stmt = $mysqli->query("SELECT FoodId, DanName FROM FoodInfo WHERE DanName LIKE '%$value%'");
    while ($loop = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
        print '<option value="'.$loop[FoodId].'">'.$loop[DanName].'</option>';
    }
print '</select>';
}
```

`$arr` looks something like this:

```
Array ( [0] => mel [1] => ost [2] => mælk ).
```

But only last value [2] is processed.

**Followup answers**
I want multiple dropdowns with multiple selects.
All dropdowns are displayed, but only last dropdown get's filled from database.

Comment: Question: Do you actually see the multiple select dropdowns, but is only the selected selection getting back over to PHP ?

Comment: Other question, seen as I don't know your context: You do want to have MULTIPLE dropdown boxes, with MULTIPLE values in each dropdown box, right? Or did you only want to have 1 dropdown box with MULTIPLE values ?

Comment: I see the multiple select dropdowns, but only one is filled with values from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, your dropdowns should not have the same name in the form of an array `a[]`. Now you have multiple dropdown boxed, but they all have the same name. Only use array names if you can have a multiple select. (Eg a list where you hold down the shift key while making multiple select. Or with checkboxes.

It also doens't make a lot of sense, because you wouldn't have a reference to which dropdown box belongs to which selected value.

Second, as already suggested, escape your values before putting them in HTML components. I would suggest you use `htmlspecialchars()` for this.

Third, encapsulate your named array keys. `$loop[FoodId]` => `$loop['FoodId']`. This might prevent notices/warnings that might break your HTML.

Actually, I'm not sure if you want to have MULTIPLE dropdown boxes, with MULTIPLE values in each. Or you just want to have 1 dropdown box with MULTIPLE values in it.

**In the first case:**

Try it like this:

```
$arr = explode("\n", $ingredients);
for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
    print '<select size="1" name="a{$i}"><option>'.htmlspecialchars($arr[$i]).'</option>';
    $stmt = $mysqli->query("SELECT FoodId, DanName FROM FoodInfo WHERE DanName LIKE '%{$arr[$i]}%'");
        while ($loop = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
            print '<option value="'.$loop['FoodId'].'">'.htmlspecialchars($loop['DanName']).'</option>';
        }
    print '</select>';
}
```

Then in PHP look back for `$_REQUEST['a0']`, `$_REQUEST['a1']`, `$_REQUEST['a2']`, etc...

**In the second case**:

Try it like this:

```
$arr = explode("\n", $ingredients);
print '<select size="1" name="a"><option>'.htmlspecialchars($value).'</option>';
foreach($arr as $value){
    $stmt = $mysqli->query("SELECT FoodId, DanName FROM FoodInfo WHERE DanName LIKE '%$value%'");
        while ($loop = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
            print '<option value="'.$loop['FoodId'].'">'.htmlspecialchars($loop['DanName']).'</option>';
        }
}
print '</select>';
```

Thus moving the `<select>` outside the foreach. In PHP then look for `$_REQUEST['a']`.

**EDIT**

As per comments below, normalize your newlines:

```
$ingredients = str_replace("\r","\n", $ingredients); // normalize
$ingredients = str_replace("\n\n","\n", $ingredients); // normalize
$arr = explode("\n", $ingredients);
for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
    print '<select size="1" name="a{$i}"><option>'.htmlspecialchars($arr[$i]).'</option>';
    $stmt = $mysqli->query("SELECT FoodId, DanName FROM FoodInfo WHERE DanName LIKE '%{$arr[$i]}%'");
        while ($loop = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
            print '<option value="'.$loop['FoodId'].'">'.htmlspecialchars($loop['DanName']).'</option>';
        }
    print '</select>';
}
```

Comment: First; It really doesen't matter to know them from each other, but great idea anyway.

Second; I used prepared statements before, but removed it for testing.

Third; I haven't had problems, but again great info, tanks.

I want to have MULTIPLE dropdown boxes, with MULTIPLE values in each.

Comment: @Sims Ok, seen your follow up answers, I would really say that you need to check if you have any values in the database, as all code looks ok. So in table `FoodInfo`, do you have any rows with `DanName` being `mel` or `ost` ?

Comment: I do, if `ost` or `mel` is last in the array, i get a lot of results. I think the problem is somewhere in the mysqli.

Comment: I dare not ask, but is the `FoodId` maybe `null` sometimes ?

Comment: No, it's not NULL anywhere.

Comment: Please do `print_r($ingredients);` and show me the output. also, in the while do `print_r($loopt);` and show me those outputs. You can try to do this on pastebin.com and place just the link here, because maybe it's a lot of output.

Comment: You say : `print_r($ingredients); outputs: "ost mel mælk" (The user input)` So there is only a space between them, and no new-line ? So the code `$arr = explode("\n", $ingredients);` returns an array with only 1 item? Or did you not take the print_r values from the page source , losing the new-lines that way ?

Comment: print_r($ingredients); is with new-line between, didn't get the value from source. print_r($ing); returns a array contains the three items from user-input.

Comment: I'm starting to run out of ideas :) ... Try `$stmt2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT FoodId, DanName FROM FoodInfo");
    while ($loop2 = $stmt2->fetch_assoc()) print_r($loop2);` at the top of the code, and pastebin the results... Let's check why the query doesn't seem to find any Mel or Ost. Are you sure you're not running into case sensitivity problems?

Comment: Also try doing this at the top: `$ingredients = str_replace("\r","\n", $ingredients); $ingredients = str_replace("\n\n","\n", $ingredients);` so normalize the newlines.

Comment: Just to start all over; User inputs mel, ost, mælk. What ever is the last get processed by the script/database. The 2 first is listed, but nothing comes from the database.

Comment: Did you try my previous comment about normalizing the newlines? On windows machines, user would maybe insert with `\r\n`, and when you split on `\n`, your array would contain: `mel\r`, `ost\r` and `mælk` ... That could be the reason why only the last is found.

Comment: $ingredients = str_replace("\r","\n", $ingredients); $ingredients = str_replace("\n\n","\n", $ingredients); gives no result, NOTHING comes out of it.

Comment: Nothing should it just changes $ingredients. So put it above the code you already had. And see if it changes anything.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, removed print from some lines by accident, the normalizing of the newlines works perfect! THANK you very much.

Comment: Ok, you're welcome. Please mark the answer as accepted. You can do so by checking the green checkbox to the left of the answer. (Or you can also upvote the answer.)

Comment: Okay, would you please clean up your answer?

Comment: @Sims It has an edit at the bottom, reflecting the changes in the comments. I leave the rest in there in case it might help others who have other issues.

Answer (score 0):

The array keys in `$loop[FoodId]` and `$loop[DanName]` need to be quoted, or PHP will treat them like un-initialized constants. Also, you should probably be running these through an HTML encoding, to prevent attacks like XSS. Making some assumptions about your desired results, you might want to try something like this as the body of your while loop:

```
$foodId  = htmlentities($loop['FoodId'], ENT_COMPAT|ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8');
$danName = htmlentities($loop['DanName'], ENT_COMPAT|ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8');
echo '<option value="'.$foodId.'">'.$danName.'</option>';
```

Also, it's unclear where $ingredients originated, but if it's in any way affected by user-input, you really should consider using a parameterized query with the $value as a bound parameter. Unfortunately, the mysqli API can make this kind of painful, so you might want to consider switching to [php:PDO](http://php.net/pdo) instead; if not, [php:mysqli.prepare](http://php.net/mysqli.prepare) is probably a good place to start.

Comment: I'm using prepared statements, it's just removed for testing right now . Also i'm using preg_replace on outputs that's affected by user-input.

Comment: Good to hear, although I'd urge you to consider htmlentities() over preg_replace(). Maintaining your own regex table of characters when htmlentities() already provides one is probably not a fantastic idea. :)

Comment: Okay, thanks for your concern about security, great information :)